# Forecast Horizon in Azure ML

Tags: azure

I'm a beginner and trying to use Azure Machine Learning Studio to run a forecasting task automatically, but I'm very confused about **how to determine the parameter - Forecast Horizon**.
I have found some explanations on the [official website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-use-automated-ml-for-ml-models).

***forecast horizon**: Indicate how many time units (minutes/hours/days/weeks/months/years) will the model be able to predict to the future. The further the model is required to predict into the future, the less accurate it becomes.*

My data increments each hour and I want to predict the values of the next 24 hours one time (namely, multistep-ahead forecasting). **Should I set Forecast Horizon to be 24?**
In addition, I have run the forecasting experiments twice with the same settings except for Forecast Horizon, in which one is set to be 1 and the other is 24. I expected the predictions are more accurate with Forecast Horizon = 1 (**can I understand it with one-step forecasting?**), but it's worse, therefore I doubt my understanding of Forecast Horizon is wrong.
Here are images of my prediction results with different forecast horizons:
The test set includes all data of a year (24*365 points).

[image: Part of test set]

[image: Forecast Horizon = 1]

[image: Forecast Horizon = 24]

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Forecasting tasks, it require the `time_column_name` and `forecast_horizon` parameters to configure your experiment.

**Forecast Horizon** is the number of periods forward you want to forecast. The horizon is measured in time series frequency units. The forecaster should predict out units based on the time period of your training data, such as monthly or weekly.

In your case you can set your Frequency to hourly forecast and Forecast horizon to 24.

[image]

**REFERENCES:**
[Forecast demand with no-code automated machine learning](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/machine-learning/tutorial-automated-ml-forecast.md)

Comment: Thanks for your information. I have set the frequency to be "hour" and run the experiments with different forecast horizon. As shown in my images, the second image shows the results with forecast horizon=1, and the third image is with forecast horizon=24. It's very strange, the performance with forecast horizon=1 is worse than the other.